# PHP mongo Driver skip and limit on inner objects

Tags: php, mongodb

Hello I am using PHP driver for MongoDB and MY Array is something like this

```
stdClass Object
```

(
    [_id] => stdClass Object
        (
            [$id] => 58e0af1b9c76847c7e8b4567
        )

```
[prod_details] => stdClass Object
    (
        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [prod_id] => 1
                        [asin] => xxxxxx
                        [sku] => 1
                        [prod_name] => Windows 98: Second Edition
                        [prod_price] => 13433
                        [prod_price_f] => 13433
                        [prod_currency] => INR
                        [prod_price_min] => 
                        [prod_price_max] => 
                        [prod_quantity] => 1
                        [prod_condition] => New
                        [prod_shipping] => 60.00
                        [prod_category] => 
                        [prod_added] => 
                    )

                [11] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [prod_id] => 11
                        [asin] => xxxxxxx
                        [sku] => 11
                        [prod_name] => The Coke Machine: The Dirty Truth Behind the World's Favorite Soft Drink [Paperback] [Sep 06, 2011] Blanding, Michael
                        [prod_price] => 2500
                        [prod_price_f] => 2500
                        [prod_currency] => INR
                        [prod_price_min] => 
                        [prod_price_max] => 
                        [prod_quantity] => 8
                        [prod_condition] => New
                        [prod_shipping] => 60.00
                        [prod_category] => 
                        [prod_added] => 
                    )

                [12] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [prod_id] => 12
                        [asin] => xxxxxxx
                        [sku] => 12
                        [prod_name] => In Other Words [Hardcover] [Feb 09, 2016] Jhumpa Lahiri
                        [prod_price] => 748.9
                        [prod_price_f] => 748.9
                        [prod_currency] => INR
                        [prod_price_min] => 
                        [prod_price_max] => 
                        [prod_quantity] => 8
                        [prod_condition] => New
                        [prod_shipping] => 60.00
                        [prod_category] => 
                        [prod_added] => 
                    )
```

when I run PHP query I get ALL result and not filtered result with skip and limit

```
$collection->find(array('_id'=>new MongoId($mongoid)), array('prod_details.1' => ''))->skip(0)->limit(2);
```

Here I am traversing to prod_details >> 1 and putting limit of 0 to 2 but I get all objects. and limit is not working.

Please help.